# Ionic3 auth interceptor error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a Ionic v3 app able to consume REST APIs using an api token as logging method.
After the user performs the login, the variable *currentUser* gets set and from now then the AuthInterceptor will always send the api token attached to all requests.

However, apparently the *currentUser* is always null even though the alert in the login, used as a check, always shows the correct user first name.

**AuthInterceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    currentUser: any;

    constructor(public storage: Storage) {
        this.storage.get('currentUser').then((val) => {
            this.currentUser = JSON.parse(val);  
        });
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with api token if available

        console.log(this.currentUser);

        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser.api_token) {
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.currentUser.api_token}`
                    }
                });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

**AuthSvc.ts**

```
 login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>('login', { email: email, password: password })
            .map(data => {
                // login successful if there's an api token in the response
                if (data.user && data.user.api_token) {

                    this.setUser(data.user);

                    return data.user;
                } 
            });
    }

setUser(user) {
        console.log('setUser');
        // store user details and the token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        this.storage.set("currentUser", JSON.stringify(user));
    }
```

**login.ts (page)**

```
this.authSvc.login(this.user.email, this.user.password)
    .subscribe(
       data => {
           alert('Hi '+data.name);
           this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
       },
       error => {
    });
```

The API returns a JSON object consisting of

```
{
 "success": true,
 "user": User obj
}
```

Comment: Well where do you actually set the user to the storage? Cant see anywhere...

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: This is asynchronous, if you console log the currentuser inside the `then` callback, it would have value I bet :) I didn't notice that at first ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2